# Ruby chunk and compare two large files

Tags: ruby

Looking for direction on how to chunk and compare two large text files using ruby. Any help is appreciated. Something like 100 lines at a time.

tried:

```
file(file1).foreach.each_slice(100) do |lines|
  pp lines
end
```

getting confused how to include the second file to this loop.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out whether two files have the exact same contents, or something more complex?

Comment: thats right trying to figure they have same content trying to read 100 lines at a time

Comment: >trying to figure they have same content ..... Why not calculate the md5 sum of each file, and compare those? If all you're interested in is "are they the same".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438651/process-two-files-at-the-same-time-in-ruby.

Comment: @tadman The probability of two hashes accidentally colliding is 1/2^128 which is 1 in 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456. This is not something to worry about, unless you're making *trillions* of checks per *second*.

Comment: Possibly [relevant question](http://superuser.com/questions/174283/how-to-diff-large-files-on-linux) provides a number of options on Linux/POSIX systems.

Answer (score 3):

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 256 # bytes
def same? path1, path2
  return false unless [path1, path2].map { |f| File.size f }.reduce &:==

  f1, f2 = [path1, path2].map { |f| File.new f }

  loop do
    s1, s2 = [f1, f2].map { |f| f.read(CHUNK_SIZE) }
    break false if s1 != s2
    break true if s1.nil? || s1.length < CHUNK_SIZE
  end
ensure
  [f1, f2].each &:close
end
```

*UPD*: credits for fixed typo and file size comparison goes to @tadman.

Comment: This is, technically speaking, a good answer. But it comes with no framing or explanation of what the code is doing, for an asker who is new to trying to solve this kind of problem. I'd recommend adding some framing and comments to explain.

Comment: I think there's a small syntax error on the third line, but otherwise was roughly what I was thinking: Read in chunks at a time, compare. Make sure you don't exhaust either before finishing. A quick test at the start on file-size would avoid a lot of heavy lifting.

Comment: It's not necessary, or desirable to use "UPD:", or any of the variants, to mark sections in questions or answers. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/153968

Answer (score 3):

Just "[Process two files at the same time in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438651/process-two-files-at-the-same-time-in-ruby)" and compare by chunks, like this:

```
f1 = File.open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = File.open('file2.txt', 'r')

f1.each_slice(10).zip(f2.each_slice(10)).each do |line1, line2|
  return false unless line1 == line2
end
return true
```

Or, as suggested by @meagar (in this case line by line):

```
f1.each_line.zip(f2.each_line).all? { |a,b| a == b }
```

This will return `true` if files identical.

Comment: Or, `f1.each_line.zip(f2.each_line).all? { |a,b| a == b }`. It'd be interesting to see whether `each_slice` is actually any faster, since I assume the file IO is internally buffered regardless.

Comment: You should either pass a block to `open` or close the files in an `ensure` block.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one, the approach is similar to [mudasobwa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37030867/477037):

```
def same?(file_1, file_2)
  return true if File.identical?(file_1, file_2)
  return false unless File.size(file_1) == File.size(file_2)

  buf_size = 2 ** 15 # 32 K
  buf_1 = ''
  buf_2 = ''

  File.open(file_1) do |f1|
    File.open(file_2) do |f2|
      while f1.read(buf_size, buf_1) && f2.read(buf_size, buf_2)
        return false unless buf_1 == buf_2
      end
    end
  end
  true
end
```

In the first two lines perform quick checks for identical files (e.g. hard and soft links) and same size using [`File.identical?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html#method-c-identical-3F) and [`File.size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html#method-c-size).

[`File.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html#method-c-open) opens each file in read-only mode. The `while` loop then keeps calling [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-read) to read 32K chunks from each file into the buffers `buf_1` and `buf_2` until EOF. If the buffers differ, `false` is returned. Otherwise, i.e. without encountering any differences, `true` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Just compare those files line by line:

```
def same_file?(path1, path2)
  file1 = File.open(path1)
  file2 = File.open(path2)
  return true if File.absolute_path(path1) == File.absolute_path(path2)
  return false unless file1.size == file2.size
  enum1 = file1.each
  enum2 = file2.each

  loop do
    # It's a mystery that the loop really ends
    # when any of the 2 files has nothing to read
    return false unless enum1.next == enum2.next
  end

  return true
ensure
  file1.close
  file2.close
end
```

---

I did my homework and found in the [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) documentation:

> `StopIteration` raised in the block breaks the loop. In this case, loop returns the "result" value stored in the exception.

And, in the [`Enumerator#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) documentation:

> When the position reached at the end, `StopIteration` is raised.

So the mystery is no longer a mystery for me.

Comment: I was just about to ask how the loop exited. Thanks for that clarification, even if that clarification is "It's a mystery!"

Comment: `next` raises `StopIteration` when reaching the end which breaks the loop.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for clarification. I think I'll dig more deeply into `Enumerator` and `Proc`

Comment: If I could upvote this a second time for explaining that mystery, I would. Nice work.

Comment: I suggest converting the potentially relative filespecs to absolute ones for the comparison, using `File.absolute_path`:    `return true if File.absolute_path(path1) == File.absolute_path(path2)`

Comment: @KeithBennett Thanks for the suggestion. Updated.

Comment: Do you need `ensure`? I upvoted, even though I don't care what you think. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To determine if two files have the exact same content, without comparing the actual content of the same chunk of each file, you can use a checksum function that turns the data into a hash string in a deterministic way. And while you have to read the contents to checksum it, you can get checksums for each slice, and end up with an array of checksums for each file.

You can then compare the collection of checksums. If the two files have the exact same content, the two collections will be equal.

```
require 'digest/md5'

hashes1 = File.foreach('./path_to_file').each_slice(100).map do |slice|
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(slice)
end
hashes2 = File.read('./path_to_duplicate').each_slice(100).map do |slice|
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(slice)
end

hashes1.join == hashes2.join
#=> true, meaning the two files contain the same content
```

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit misleading. You can't calculate a checksum without reading the files.

Comment: @Stefan But you don't have to read the entire file *into memory*. These files could be gigabytes in size.

Comment: It's worth noting that two files can differ but have same digest. The possibility is so remote, however, that it's not something to worry about.

Comment: @Matt I think it's better to read some data from the 2 files into memory, compare them and forget them, then read some more data ...

Comment: @Aetherus I agree, which is why I upvoted your answer. :D But I'll be editing this one to reflect that.

Comment: I don't see how calculating an MD5 hash can be faster than comparing the bytes.

Comment: It's not. Go upvote @Aetherus' answer, because it's better.

Comment: Regarding your update, this is the *wrong* way to go about using hashes for this purpose! When people were talking about "not reading the entire file into memory", they were talking about streaming data into MD5 and producing a single hash for each file, not just chunking the file into 100 line groups and *individually* hashing those chunks. If you're just going to read chunks, hash and then compare hashes, there is **no value** to hashing at all. Just compare the chunks directly using `==`. It's *far* slower to hash each chunk and compare the hashes, for absolutely no gain.

Comment: Matt, it's not at all petty. The point is that opinions are of no value here. That's important. My choice of language was for emphases. I would have said the same if I were addressing anyone (other that Matz, perhaps). Does anyone care what I think? I hope not.

Comment: There is one situation where there's much to be said for this approach: when the two files are not at the same physical location. In that case.only the digest for one need be transmitted. Many moons ago, when data transmission was much slower and more expensive, I may have been the first to use this technique for remote computer backup. Digests for new and changed files were first transmitted to a central server. Then only those files not already in our "library" were physically transmitted to the server, to be added to the library. As most file were program files, this was a huge time-saver.

Answer (score 1):

## Benchmark time

(Matt's answer is not included because I couldn't get it working)

#### Results 1 KB file size (N = 10000)

```
                          user     system      total        real
aetherus              0.510000   0.300000   0.810000 (  0.823201)
meagar                0.350000   0.160000   0.510000 (  0.512755)
mudasobwa             0.290000   0.200000   0.490000 (  0.500831)
stefan                0.150000   0.160000   0.310000 (  0.312743)
yevgeniy_anfilofyev   0.320000   0.170000   0.490000 (  0.497157)
```

#### Results 1 MB file size (N = 100)

```
                          user     system      total        real
aetherus              1.540000   0.110000   1.650000 (  1.667937)
meagar                1.170000   0.130000   1.300000 (  1.310278)
mudasobwa             1.470000   0.830000   2.300000 (  2.313481)
stefan                0.010000   0.030000   0.040000 (  0.045577)
yevgeniy_anfilofyev   0.570000   0.100000   0.670000 (  0.677226)
```

#### Results 1 GB file size (N = 1)

```
                          user     system      total        real
aetherus             15.570000   0.920000  16.490000 ( 16.525826)
meagar               24.170000   1.910000  26.080000 ( 26.190057)
mudasobwa            16.260000   8.160000  24.420000 ( 24.471977)
stefan                0.120000   0.330000   0.450000 (  0.443074)
yevgeniy_anfilofyev  12.940000   1.310000  14.250000 ( 14.295736)
```

#### Notes

- mudasobwa's code runs significantly faster with larger `CHUNK_SIZE`
- with identical chunk sizes, stefan's code seems to be ~2x faster than mudasobwa's code
- "fastest" chunk size is somewhere between 16 K and 512 K
- I couldn't use [fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) because the 1 GB test would have taken too long

#### Code

```
def aetherus_same?(f1, f2)
  enum1 = f1.each
  enum2 = f2.each
  loop do
    return false unless enum1.next == enum2.next
  end
  return true
end

def meagar_same?(f1, f2)
  f1.each_line.zip(f2.each_line).all? { |a,b| a == b }
end

CHUNK_SIZE = 256 # bytes
def mudasobwa_same?(f1, f2)
  loop do
    s1, s2 = [f1, f2].map { |f| f.read(CHUNK_SIZE) }
    break false if s1 != s2
    break true if s1.nil? || s1.length < CHUNK_SIZE
  end
end

def stefan_same?(f1, f2)
  buf_size = 2 ** 15 # 32 K
  buf_1 = ''
  buf_2 = ''
  while f1.read(buf_size, buf_1) && f2.read(buf_size, buf_2)
    return false unless buf_1 == buf_2
  end
  true
end

def yevgeniy_anfilofyev_same?(f1, f2)
  f1.each_slice(10).zip(f2.each_slice(10)).each do |line1, line2|
    return false unless line1 == line2
  end
  return true
end

FILE1 = ARGV[0]
FILE2 = ARGV[1]
N     = ARGV[2].to_i

def with_files
  File.open(FILE1) { |f1| File.open(FILE2) { |f2| yield f1, f2 } }
end

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm(19) do |x|
  x.report('aetherus')             { N.times { with_files { |f1, f2| aetherus_same?(f1, f2) } } }
  x.report('meagar')               { N.times { with_files { |f1, f2| meagar_same?(f1, f2) } } }
  x.report('mudasobwa')            { N.times { with_files { |f1, f2| mudasobwa_same?(f1, f2) } } }
  x.report('stefan')               { N.times { with_files { |f1, f2| stefan_same?(f1, f2) } } }
  x.report('yevgeniy_anfilofyev')  { N.times { with_files { |f1, f2| yevgeniy_anfilofyev_same?(f1, f2) } } }
end
```